# Using Python scripting to plot integration of a variable over a line versus time in ParaView

Tags: python, paraview, openfoam

I have some OpenFOAM simulation results (you may use the official `can.ex2` model which can be downloaded from [here](https://midas3.kitware.com/midas/item/207317)). What I want to do is:

1. open a file, load the original data as decomposed case (which can't be applied to the case above)
2. apply a Calculator filter one a specific variable (e.g. `DISP*3.14*coordsX`, I used 3.14 because for the love of god I can't find Pi!)
3. apply filter plot over line `[x1,y1,z1]` to `[x2,y2,z2]`
4. integrate the output of 2 over the line defined in 3 in each time step
5. plot the result of 4 over time

I would appreciate if you could help me know how I can write a Python script to do this.

Comment: For 2: from math import pi.

It's not clear what kind of file you're using. If it's csv-like, you can use the csv module in the standard library.

Comment: @GeorgeG In Python I know how to use Pi, however if you check the ParaView Calculator filter property section there are no pi. of course when in Python this issue would be resolved. Unless ParaView API accepts expressions as strings...

Comment: Ah, I've never used that before, sorry.

Comment: @GeorgeG no problem. I haven't used the python scripting in Parview either. I couldn't even find a good 'for dummies' example.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to write a Python script to do this is to use ParaView's Python Trace capabilities. Basically, you start a trace and then run through the actions you've listed in the Paraview user interface. ParaView translates your actions into a Python script that you can save and modify after stopping the trace. See Section 1.6.2 of the [ParaView Guide](https://www.paraview.org/paraview-guide/) for more information. It is probably the single best way to learn about Python scripting for ParaView.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I will read that section, though I still have [issues](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/render-causes-a-non-responding-visualization-toolkit-win32opengl-on-windows/538) with VTK!

Comment: According to the Guide there must be a `Python shell` in the `Tools` menu. I can't find it though. it is not there!

Comment: Found the `Python shell`. it is in the `View` menu. For the record on mac there is this nice feature on `Help` menu where one can search for commands and selecting the item a blue arrow shows the exact place. Wonder why this feature is not on Windows GUI!

Comment: I tried your suggestion to do all the steps once via GUI and trace. I also used @mathieu-westphal method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407769/4999991) to interact with ParaView GUI. However the result is not what I expect as can be seen in the image in the gist. It opens all the pans but does not apply any of the filters! I would appreciate if you could help me know what is wrong and how I can solve it.

Comment: I also tried removing the `Connect("localhost")` and loading the python script from `Menu>Macro>Add new macro` it shows the first step but again it does not apply the rest. please see `paraview_GUI_result_2.png`

Comment: I just realised that I haven't mentioned [the Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/cad475a092167fbc2ec4be9e1b26ba71)!