# ParaView Python script causes non responding Visualization Toolkit - Win32OpenGL on Windows

Tags: python, windows, vtk, paraview, qvtkwidget

As I have reported [here](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/render-causes-a-non-responsive-visualization-toolkit-win32opengl-on-windows/538) when I try to render the cone example by:

```
from paraview.simple import *
cone = Cone()
Show(cone)
Render()
```

I get a non responding window:

[image]

[image]

My version of Python is:

> Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

and I’m on Windows 10 64-bit. I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `Interact()` method.

```
from paraview.simple import *
cone = Cone()
Show(cone)
Interact()
```

use the `q` key to stop the interaction.

Comment: I could not reply over there because of `the maximum number of replies a new user can create on their first day` :) but thanks. this is an awesome solution. now it is completely responsive except when trying to close the window. Is there a python command to stop rendering and close the VTK window from within Python?

Comment: On the side note, I wonder why the `Render()` is not being replaced completely with `Interact()`? I mean when there is the later why former?!

Comment: yes, the command is `q` key, while the VTK window has the focus. Most people using pvpython are actually generating screenshots and do not interact at all.

Comment: BTW I like the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407769/4999991) better.

Comment: `q` does not close the window but only stop the interaction. Allowing you to do other stuff in the command.

Comment: Ok. So there is no way to close this window in a peaceful way :) I'm trying to solve my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206088/using-python-scripting-to-plot-integration-of-a-variable-over-a-line-versus-time) using the [other method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46407769/4999991) you suggested. But I have some issues. I will report it below @cory-quammen answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214249/4999991)

Comment: Not that I could think of no. Sure, do not hesitate to tag me.

Comment: You can use `Disconnect()` to close all windows and reset pvpython